# Can't locate object method method "sub_" via package "Test::Base::BaseClass"

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
BaseClass.pm

package Test::Base::BaseClass;

sub new {

    return bless {hello=>@_[0],person=>@_[1]} , __PACKAGE__;    
}

sub hello {
    print "hello";
}

sub person {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{person};
}

1;

Sub.pm
package Test::Base::BaseClass;


sub sub_ {

    my $self= shift;
    print __PACKAGE__;

}

1;

example.pl

use lib 'C:/Users/pavan.t/workspace/Simple';
use Test::Base::BaseClass;
$sub =  Test::Base::BaseClass->new('pavan','pavan');

print $sub->person;
print $sub->sub_
```

I have one BaseClass package and another module Sub.pm which belongs to same package.

In my example program, when i call the `sub_` method, it prints the following error as:

> Can't locate object method "sub_" via package "Test::Base::BaseClass" at C:/Users/pavan.t/workspace/Simple/ExampleOnBase.pl line 12.

Comment: That should be `sub new { return bless {hello=>@_[1],person=>@_[2]}, $_[0]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a package `Foo::Bar::Baz`, perl is searching for a file `foo/bar/baz.pm` somewhere in the `INC` path.
Your script uses `Test::Base::BaseClass` so it finds `BaseClass.pm`. There's no `sub sub_` defined.

You should be able to add a `use Sub`, no matter which package is defined in there.

However, packages and file names should (they don't have to but it's better!) be similar.